# Android Display result in Hindi

Tags: java, android, textview

In my Android application a message is displayed in a text-view and the message is taken from server.. I updated both English and font in Hindi.. the English language is displaying correctly and when I tried to add Hindi text ,,..  ' ????? ' is displaying instead of text..

I tried. ..this code.. also..

```
 txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


                            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                    "fonts/hindi.ttf");
                            txt4.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: Does your device support Hindi fonts??

Comment: I checked it in Emulator

Comment: Check it on real device.

Comment: and in the logcat also .. the message displaying is '??????'

Comment: i guess your device needs Hindi Font library

Comment: i already installed .. a hindi font in assets/font folder

Comment: Install a sample Hindi application from PlayStore and check it on your device.You will know whether your device suports Hindi fonts or not.

Comment: you need to give UTF-8 suport

Comment: Let me check Siddharth.. Thanks for your help

Comment: I checked... i installed an android app with hindi font.. it is displaying font.. but again I am getting ''' ???????' instead of texts when i installed my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the details in server sometimes the problems can happen because of the special characters. If you copy and pasted the text from somewhere, this problem can happen. You can overcome this situation by editing the special characters and typing them inside the table.